# How to reverse Elementary OS tweak tool changes

Tags: gnome, elementary-os

I installed elementary os and made a few changes through gnome tweak tool, when i first did the changes it did not seem like changes took effect on anything but when i rebooted in the morning, the user interface was too slow and close buttons were gone also i cannot do any change in Dock, i was using it transparent but now i cannot change anything related to it. I searched a lot but i could not reverse the changes i made, any opinion is appreciated.

PS. i already uninstalled gnome tweak tool but it changed nothing.

Comment: Please be aware that [Gnome Tweak Tool](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/GnomeTweakTool) and [elementary Tweaks](https://launchpad.net/elementary-tweaks) are not the same!

Answer (score 0):

If uninstalled - reinstall elementary-tweak-tool. Then, open settings and go into tweaks. You should then see a little yellow arrow next to each option - these will reset the value to default (which is what you're looking for)